# Google certificate crash warning when publishing an update to play store

Tags: android, xamarin, google-api, google-play-services, google-maps

I recently updated my app to target Android API 29 and trying to publish an update to my app.
Pre-launch test results in-play console throws an error

```
Java.lang.securityexception : Googlecertificatesrslt : package signed with debug key.
```

I'm using the same key for a long time, and I did do beta testing on android 9.
Any Idea why that crash warning?
Does it really go to crash on android 8?

Comment: Make sure you are uploading the release version of the app.

Comment: Yes, I'm. I can see the app in beta listing in the play store